# Minimal hausdorff spaces and adherence of open filter

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $(X,\mathscr{T})$ be a minimal Hausdorff space. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be an open filter such that it has a unique adherent point, say $x$. Let $\mathscr{T'}$ be the collection of all open sets in $X$ not containing $x$ together with elements of $\mathscr{F}$. How can we prove that $\mathscr{T'}$ is a Hausdorff topology on $X$ ?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: That isn’t quite the topology that we need. (I think that may have said so in a comment, but if so, I was a bit careless.) Let $\mathscr{N}=\{U\in\mathscr{F}:x\in U\}$, and let $\tau'=\mathscr{N}\cup\{U\in\tau:x\notin U\}\subseteq\tau$. We must first check that $\tau'$ is a topology on $X$.

- Clearly $\varnothing,X\in\tau'$.
- Let $U,V\in\tau'$. If $x\notin U$, then $x\notin U\cap V$, so $U\cap V\in\mathscr{N}$. Similarly, $U\cap V\in\mathscr{N}$ if $x\notin V$. And if $x\in U\cap V$, then $U,V\in\mathscr{N}$, which is a filter (check this!), so $U\cap V\in\mathscr{F}\subseteq\tau'$.
- Finally, let $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau'$; I’ll leave it to you to show that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau'$. You’ll need two cases.

Then we need to show that $\tau'$ is Hausdorff. Let $y$ and $z$ be distinct points of $X$.

- Use the fact that $\tau$ is Hausdorff to show that if $y\ne x\ne z$, there are disjoint $U,V\in\tau'$ such that $y\in U$ and $z\in V$.
- If $y=x$, use the fact that $x$ is the unique cluster point of $\mathscr{F}$ to show that there are disjoint $U,V\in\tau'$ such that $y\in U$ and $z\in V$.

Comment: @Henno: You’re absolutely right: I didn’t notice that the OP’s $\tau'$ wasn’t quite the right topology. It should be okay now.

Comment: It's fine now. Good to see I wasn't crazy :)